# Result of a query filter to List Python

Tags: python, django

I did a query filter and the result returned is in a tuple form. I want it to be in a list.

```
project_work = Project.objects.filter(title = topic).values()
lip = []

for con in project_work:
    lip.append(con)
```

And this is the output:

> [{'id': 24, 'title': 'A mobile-based distress calls management system
>   for security departments in tertiary institutions', 'reg_num_id':
>   '2014/15634', 'supervisor': 'Mr. Jeff', 'platform': 'MA', 'year':
>   '2018'}]

But i want a list like this:

> [A mobile-based distress calls management system for security
>   departments in tertiary institutions', '2014/15634',....]

Comment: Shouldn't this be a list of lists then, what if multiple `Project`s have the same title?

Comment: The aim is to make sure that no two or more little can be the same.

Comment: then you should use `.get(..)` not `.filter(..)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you should use `.values_list(..)` and not <s>`.values(..)`</s>:

```
project_work = Project.objects.filter(title = topic).values_list()
```

This will return a **list of tuples**, since your filter can - at least in theory - return *no* or *multiple* rows, hence we use a list.

If you want to convert the tuples to a list, you can perform a `map`ping on these:

```
project_work = list(map(list, Project.objects.filter(title = topic).values_list()))
```

So this will give you something like:

```
[
    ['A mobile-based distress calls management system for security departments in tertiary institutions', '2014/15634',....]
]
```

In case you know that there is exactly one such element, you can use `.get(..)` instead:

```
project_work = list(Project.objects.values_list().get(title=topic))
```

This will produce something like:

```
['A mobile-based distress calls management system for security departments in tertiary institutions', '2014/15634',....]
```

Note that if you do not specify the order of the values (as parameters of the `values_list`, then it will pick the order in which Django represents the fields, which can be rather chaotic.

Comment: it has helped in some way but, this  "project_work = list(map(list, Project.objects.filter(title = topic).values_list()))"  is showing "map attribute has no object meta".

Comment: Did you by any change have overwritten `list`, or `map`? Don't do that... Builtins (and in fact any identifier) is better never overwritten with something different.

Comment: Please can you throw more light?

Comment: @FrameP: you probably defined some function `def list(..)` or `def map(..)` or wrote something like `list = ...`. SInce that will override the reference to the `list` or `map` builtin.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
for con in project_work:
    lip.append(list(con.values()))
```